# How to use recursion on a list of lists that doesn't follow a predictable pattern

Tags: python, list, recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to create a function that takes in a list of lists and returns a Binary Tree form the elements in the list of lists. The list of lists follow this format: ["**root**", "**left subtree**", "**right subtree**"]

How can i use recursion to parse through a list of lists and create a Binary tree.
The main problem is that the list of list does not necessarily follow the same pattern.

So, for example :

```
lst = ['root', ['left_child', 'leaf' , 'leaf'], ['right_child', 'leaf', 'leaf']]
```

but it can also be:

```
lst =  ['root', [], ['right_child', ['leaf', 'value', 'value'] , 'leaf']]
```

There are many different conditions that can vary upon different types of lists,so the main problem boils down how to use recursion to go through a list of list that does not follow a predictable pattern other than  ["**root**", "**left subtree**", "**right subtree**"]. What kind of conditional statements would help me to avoid index errors.

**Note:
The class BinaryTree has setLeft and setRight built in already and asks for a root upon initialization**

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Is `leaf` a keyword or just a sample value?

Comment: it is a sample value

Answer (score 1):

This *is* a predictable pattern; it is just that a tree can also be an empty list or a string (that is, a leaf).  So that is you pattern: any time you can have a tree, it can take one of three forms:

1. an empty list, which likely corresponds to `None` in your BinaryTree, but I can't say for sure
2. a string, a leaf, which I also don't know how your BinaryTree handles
3. a full binary tree node, which you seem to understand already.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation I spun up in a few minutes. Builds a binary tree from a list and then does an in-order traversal to verify the tree was built correctly. I'm using isinstance of to verify whether the node is a leaf(ie: a string) or not (ie: a list) but this is a bit of a hack.

```
class Tree:

    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self.root = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def in_order_print(self):
        if self.root is None:
            return
        if isinstance(self.left, Tree):
            self.left.in_order_print()
        print self.root
        if isinstance(self.right, Tree):
            self.right.in_order_print()


def grab(alist):
    return alist[0], alist[1], alist[2]


def recurse_it(atree, alist):
    if alist == [] or isinstance(alist, basestring):
        return
    root, left, right = grab(alist)
    atree.root = root
    atree.left = Tree(left)
    atree.right = Tree(right)
    recurse_it(atree.left, left)
    recurse_it(atree.right, right)

    return atree


def list_to_tree(alist):
    return recurse_it(Tree(), alist)


def main():
    lst1 = ['root', ['left_child', 'leaf', 'leaf'],
            ['right_child', 'leaf', 'leaf']]

    lst2 = ['root', [], ['right_child', ['leaf', 'value', 'value'], 'leaf']]

    thetree1 = list_to_tree(lst1)
    thetree1.in_order_print()

    print '___________________________'

    thetree2 = list_to_tree(lst2)
    thetree2.in_order_print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


"""
Tree1:
                       [ root ]
                  [left]      [right]
               [leaf][leaf] [leaf][leaf]


Tree2: 
                       [ root ]
                  []          [right]
                         [leaf]     [leaf]
                   [value][value]  
"""
```